# Angular 4 index.html won't load any script

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular

This is frustrating, I'm trying to load a simple script inside my `index.html` but I get 404.

**index.html**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Login</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/scripts/angular-cookies.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is my project structure**

[image]

**This is the error I get - 404**

[image]

The file is there and it's not empty. I tried also:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app/scripts/angular-cookies.js">
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/scripts/angular-cookies.js">
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/scripts/angular-cookies.js">
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You're missing the first folder 'src' in your path to the scripts.

Comment: If you are using angular 2/4 this link maybe will help you to setup an external library inside your project https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/

Comment: you need to put the file in `assets` and reference like: `<script src="assets/yourfile.js">`. I guess you're using Angular 2 so you should change `angularjs` tag

Comment: @Mickers it's not it, I've just tried

Comment: @sTx it was it! I make a few more tests to be sure...

Comment: remember to do this to any other external resource like: scripts, styles, images, video etc.

Comment: @MarlonBarcarol I'm using Angular4 btu thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into it.

Comment: @sTx if you write the comment as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I've mentioned in comment, any external resource should be placed in `assets` folder and for your case referenced like `<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/angular-cookies.js">` considering `assets` contains a folder named `scripts` which contains your `angular-cookies.js` file. After building the code the resulted `www` folder will be like:

- assets -> which contains the external files
- build -> which contains your ts files transpiled into js files
- index.html
- other files

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it will be fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/src/app/scripts/angular-cookies.js">
```

Or maybe

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/app/scripts/angular-cookies.js">
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not it.

Comment: There's no way you 'have' to put the scripts in an assets folder... You can put your scripts anywhere you like and as long as you reference the path correctly (which I see you're doing it wrong in a few places) it will work. Only thing I can think of is if you're using some loading library I've never heard of that requires an assets folder...

Comment: Sometimes that is depend on your project structure, have a try and let me know(But i think it will make no difference.)